# Validating dates in zend framework (comparing two)

Tags: php, zend-framework, validation, date, zend-form

I'm developing a **zend form** for a events. I wanna validate two dates such that the first one (`$date_start`) should be greater than the current date and the second one (`$date_end`) should be greater than the first one (`$date_end > $date_start`). Does anybody knows how to do it **using validators**?

Comment: Have you read this? http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.validate.writing_validators.html

Comment: just a little comment to say that you can use comparaison operators `<` and `>` on datetimes in PHP. Maybe this can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes what @ArnieRie says is right .

But as you are looking to use in Zend_Form

You can check this question : [Zend Form Validate Range Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6387792/zend-form-validate-range-date)

Same applies here. I saw the same article over http://www.oplabo.com/article/22 .

Answer (score 4):

Easy with Zend Date

```
$dateOne = new Zend_Date(time());
$dateTwo = new Zend_Date(time());

if ($dateOne->isLater($dateTwo)) {
 // do what ever
}

if ($dateOne->isEarlier($dateTwo)) {
 // do what ever
}
```